# How can I get top users in specific tags?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a function like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `user_top_tags`(`user_id` INT, `tags_num` TINYINT(1)) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8mb4
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE  top_tags varchar(50);

    SELECT substring_index(group_concat(x.name  ORDER BY x.tag_score DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', tags_num) INTO top_tags
    FROM (
        SELECT t.name, sum(r.score) AS tag_score
        FROM reputations r
        JOIN qanda_tags qt ON qt.qanda_id = r.question_id
        JOIN tags t ON t.id = qt.tag_id
        WHERE r.owner_id = user_id
        GROUP BY t.name
    ) x;

    RETURN top_tags;
END
```

And I call it like this:

```
SELECT u.name, user_top_tags(u.id, 3) FROM users u WHERE 1;
```

And it returns a list of users with their top three tags. Something like this:

```
+--------+-----------------+
| Jack   | php,oop,mysql   |
| Martin | css,js,html     |
| Peter  | jquery,js,react |
+--------+-----------------+
```

Now I want to get the users which has active in specific tags. Something like [top users page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers) in SO *(which is for `javascript` tag, but I want to get list of users in multiple tags, like `IN ('css','html')`)*.

Now should I do a join on the query? Or should I modify the function? Does anybody have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: You can do join on your query.

Comment: @SagarGangwal Yes, I guess you're right. I'm trying ... `:-)` And I guess I have to use `having` clause.

Comment: Yes if you are using `GROUP BY` then `HAVING` is best option instead of `where`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT substring_index(group_concat(x.name  ORDER BY x.tag_score DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 3) as top_tags,x.username
    FROM (
        SELECT u.name username,t.name, sum(r.score) AS tag_score
        FROM reputations r
        JOIN qanda_tags qt ON qt.qanda_id = r.question_id
        JOIN tags t ON t.id = qt.tag_id
        INNER JOIN users  u ON u.id = r.owner_id
        GROUP BY t.name,u.name
        having u.active < 10
    ) x;
```

Instead of writing function,you can achieve same business logic using simple query. Then obviously go with that query only.

You can try above query.

Here I had consider that you have some column which specify that user is active from how many days.